# Why cant i login with credentials i got from facebook sdk through firebase?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi i am having an error with facebook login using expo, facebook sdk and Firebase

```
[Error: Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"AM5hHHrnXuN4ehHi4q_mmR_"}}]
```

In my console log i can see the credentials are being received yet i still get this error and on my facebook notification i got the notification that i logged into this app, error is in firebase signInWithCredential,
also on facebook debugger : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ the token from credential logs is valid,
my code

```
import React from 'react'
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import {Button} from "react-native-paper";
import * as Facebook from "expo-facebook";

function FacebookLogin({appColor}) {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user != null && !user.isAnonymous) {
            console.log('We are authenticated now!');
        }

        // Do other things
    });

    async function LoginWithFacebook() {
        await Facebook.initializeAsync({appId: '741443520140189', appName: 'Just an app'});
        const {type, token} = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
            permissions: ['public_profile'],
        });

        if (type === "success") {
            console.log("TOKEN", token)
            const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
            console.log("credentials", credential)

            firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithCredential(credential)
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });

        }
    }

    return <Button onPress={() => LoginWithFacebook()} color={"#fff"} style={{marginTop: "20%"}}>Login</Button>
}

export default FacebookLogin
```